# Getting error while sending email from GCP composer airflow

Tags: smtp, airflow, sendgrid, http-status-code-401, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to configure email but getting following error.
when running task getting following error: -
I am using Python3 with airflow 10.3 versions in GCP Composer need help.

My **airflow.cfg**

```
[email]  
email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email  

[smtp]  
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com  
smtp_starttls = True  
smtp_ssl = False  
smtp_user = airflow  
smtp_port = 587  
smtp_password = mypassword  
smtp_mail_from = myemail@gamil.com
```

in my dag file I have created task :-
**dag.py file:-**

```py
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

email_task=EmailOperator(task_id='email_task',to="email@gamil.com", subject="test", html_content="<h1>Most important heading here</h1>", files=None, cc=None, bcc=None, mime_subtype='mixed', mime_charset='us_ascii', dag=dag)
```

Getting error:

> ERROR - HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
>   python_http_client.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorize

Answer (score 2):

The error is an Authorization error, so you need to check that you're setting your Sendgrid API Key (or password, if using a smtp-server) correctly.

Based on your airflow.cfg, it seems to me that you are trying to use both Sendgrid and a third-party smtp server.

The email flag determines which one to use. In this case, the flag `email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email` is specifying that you are going to use Sendgrid.

To [configure Sendgrid](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services) as your email server, you need to obtain your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` and set both the key and `SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM` as environment variables.

On the other hand, if you [want to use another smtp server](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_third-party_smtp_services), you have to change the email flag to `email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp`. In this case, you need to override the smtp user and password.

Answer (score 0):

With **Google Cloud Composer**, you must set the:
 *SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM*
and the:
 *SENDGRID_API_KEY*
Composer "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES"